# Picking Contact with Email

Tags: android, android-intent, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I use the following intent to pick an email-contact from the contacts app.:

```
Intent selectContact = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI);
        selectContact.setType(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_TYPE);
        startActivityForResult(selectContact, RESULT_PICK_CONTACT);
```

On activity result i try to query the returned id like this:

```
Uri contactData = intent.getData();
        String contactId = contactData.getLastPathSegment();
        Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTENT_URI,
                null,
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID.concat(" = ?"),
                new String[]{
                        contactId
                },
                null);
```

Unfortunally the Cursor i use to query the picked contact is always empty although the contact id returned seems to be valid.

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: remove space in follow code and try again: ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.CONTACT_ID.concat("=?")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Querying onto a different id solved the problem.

When picking Email contacts the `CONTACT_ID` constant doesnt seem to be the right identifier.

I changed Selection argument to use `_ID` instead:

```
ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email._ID.concat(" = ?")
```